# Find big differences in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a csv file that contains data from two led measurements. There are some mistakes in the file that gives huge sparks in the graph. I want to locate this places where this happens.

I have this code that makes two arrays that I plot.

```
x625 = np.array(df['LED Group 625'].dropna(axis=0, how='all'))


x940 = np.array(df['LED Group 940'].dropna(axis=0, how='all'))
```

Comment: can you add some data? check also `numpy.where` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will provide an answer with some artificial data since you have not posted any data yet.

So after you convert the pandas columns into a `numpy` array, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# some random data. 100 lines and 1 column
x625 = np.random.rand(100,1)

# Assume that the maximum value in `x625` is a spark.
spark = x625.max()

# Find where these spark are in the `x625` 
np.where(x625==spark)
#(array([64]), array([0]))
```

The above means that a value equal to `spark` is located on the 64th line of the 0th column.

Similarly, you can use `np.where(x625 > any_number_here)`

**If instead of the location you need to create a boolean mask use this:**

```
boolean_mask = (x625==spark)

# verify 
np.where(boolean_mask)
# (array([64]), array([0]))
```

EDIT 1

You can use `numpy.diff()` to get the element wise differences of all elements into the list (variable).

```
diffs = np.diff(x625.ravel())
```

This will have in index 0 the results of element1-element0. 
If the vaules in `diffs` are big in a specific index positio, then a spark occured in that position.

Comment: i can give some more information. I have:
 df = pd.read_csv(path), where path is a file loaction. So i have a dataset where i have multiple sparks. So i want to react when these sparks occurs. It means i need to check if the next element in the array is unaturally big. if this makes more sence. And do this multiple times in the array

Comment: That's easy. see my EDIT 1 in my answer